# Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy error

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I have found a very strange question.  As the code below, I use canvas to upload the local picture. But sometimes it occurs that chrome throw the bug 'Cross-origin image load denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy' before paint image to the canvas!  It is not the problem with the picture, because we can upload with another computer.

I'm using chrome 31, with Windows 7 x64

```
if (!options) return;
this.options = options || {};

// 图片src为必须
if (!this.options.src) return;

this._image = new Image();
this._image.crossOrigin = "*"; // 解决跨域问题，以免污染画布
this._image.src = this.options.src;

if (this.options.isMoving === undefined) this.options.isMoving = true;
if (this.options.isMouseWheel === undefined) this.options.isMouseWheel = true;
if (this.options.isResize === undefined) this.options.isResize = false;
if (this.options.fillStyle === undefined) this.options.fillStyle = 'white';
```

[You could see the error through the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avVSH.png)

Comment: What is `this.options.src`?

Comment: It's a function parameter.

Comment: What's the _value_ of the parameter?

Comment: base64 code of the local picture ....

Comment: Is it an SVG that loads other resources?

Comment: No ~ Jpg image。 And we can upload in others computers. It seems I can't read the message of the image ~ Because the output of 'this._image.width' is 0 ...

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot draw an image to a canvas unless you're allowed to read the image URL (either if it's from your own host or via CORS).

Comment: But it occurs before draw the image to the canvas. And the picture is right form the host.  And it really works with other versions of chrome in others computer ...  It's an accidental error

Comment: I have no idea why will the image form the host throw the cross-origin error